# Problema con una class llamada cs-select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema con la clase `cs-select`, la cual no me permite activar y desactivar un select.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Forma de pago:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary">
          <input type="radio" id="transferencia" name="forma_pago" value="transferencia"
          onchange="habilitar(this.value);"
          <?=($fila[ 'forma_pago']=='transferencia' )? 'checked': '';?> />
          <label for="transferencia">Transferencia</label>
          <input value="<?=($fila['forma_pago']=='transferencia')?$fila['dato_pago']:'';?>" type="hidden" name="numero_trans" size="30" maxlength="28">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary">
          <input type="radio" id="domiciliado" name="forma_pago" value="domiciliado"
          onchange="habilitar(this.value);"
          <?=($fila[ 'forma_pago']=='domiciliado' )? 'checked': '';?> />
          <label for="domiciliado">Domiciliado</label>
        </div>
        <input disabled value="<?=($fila['forma_pago']=='domiciliado')?$fila['dato_pago']:'';?>" type="text" name="domiciliado" id="domicilioC" size="30" maxlength="28">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary">
          <input type="radio" id="efectivo" name="forma_pago" value="efectivo"
          onchange="habilitar(this.value);"
          <?=($fila[ 'forma_pago']=='efectivo' )? 'checked': '';?> />
          <label for="efectivo">Efectivo</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary">
          <input type="radio" id="pagare" name="forma_pago" value="pagare"
          onchange="habilitar(this.value);"
          <?=($fila[ 'forma_pago']=='pagare' )? 'checked': '';?> />
          <label for="pagare">Pagaré</label>
        </div>
        <select name="pagare" id="pagarePlazo" disabled class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
          <?php if(($fila['dato_pago'] == '') && ($fila['forma_pago']=='pagare')){ ?>
            <option value="0"  selected>Selecciona la cantidad</option>
              <?php } ?>
            <option value="30" <?=(($fila['dato_pago']=='30') && ($fila['forma_pago']=='pagare'))?'selected':'';?>>30 </option>
            <option value="40" <?=(($fila['dato_pago']=='40') && ($fila['forma_pago']=='pagare'))?'selected':'';?>>40 </option>
            <option value="60" <?=(($fila['dato_pago']=='60') && ($fila['forma_pago']=='pagare'))?'selected':'';?>>60 </option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  //Función que nos permite habilitar o desahabilitar la opción del pagaré.
  function habilitar(value) {
    console.log(value);
    if (value == "pagare") {
      // habilitamos
      document.getElementById("pagarePlazo").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("pagare").disabled = false;
      jQuery('#pagarePlazo').removeClass('disabled');
    } else if (value != "pagare") {
      // deshabilitamos
      document.getElementById("pagarePlazo").selectedIndex = "0";
      document.getElementById("pagarePlazo").disabled = true;

      if (value == "domiciliado") {
        // habilitamos
        document.getElementById("domicilioC").disabled = false;
      } else if (value != "domiciliado") {
        // deshabilitamos
        document.getElementById("domicilioC").value = "";
        document.getElementById("domicilioC").disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? A mí tu código me habilita y deshabilita bien el select cuando seleccion "Pagaré" u otra opción.

Comment: al parecer el OP utiliza la biblioteca [SelectInspiration](https://github.com/codrops/SelectInspiration) y esta leyendo en sus fuentes no provee ningun metodo para deshabilitar los selects

Comment: Bueno gracias por la ayuda, intentaré probar otras maneras que no sea usando la biblioteca SelectInspiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que la biblioteca que utilizas no tiene una logica para manejar el estado disabled, tendrias que programarla tu mismo.

Podrias editar el mismo archivo fuente si es que tu mismo alojas el js.

En [esta linea](https://github.com/codrops/SelectInspiration/blob/master/js/selectFx.js#L271) tendrias que verificar si el elemento esta deshabilitado con `this.el.disabled`.

Sino podrias modificar el prototipo.

```js
//modificar comportamiento por defecto para no hacer nada si esta disabled
var originalToggle = SelectFx.prototype._toggleSelect;
SelectFx.prototype._toggleSelect = function() {
  if (this.el.disabled) {
    return;
  } else {
    originalToggle.call(this);
  }
};

//iniciar select
new SelectFx(document.querySelector("select.cs-select"));


function toggle() {
  var el = document.querySelector("select.cs-select");
  el.disabled = !el.disabled;
}
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  border-right: 25px solid #fff;
  border-left: 25px solid #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::before,
body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1001;
}

body::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 4% 1em 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/css/cs-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/css/cs-skin-slide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/js/selectFx.js"></script>

<section>
  <label class="select-label">Seleccionar</label>
  <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Cantidad</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
  </select>
</section>
<br/>
<button onclick="toggle()">Habilitar/deshabilitar</button>
```

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, lo que hice fue eliminar el cs-select y y probar otras maneras